# valueerror: could not convert string to float pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change one data frame value i.e 2,67% to 2.67% and need to convert it into float but it is giving me error

I have tried using below statement but it  doesn't work

```py
df.str.replace(' , ' , ' . ').astype(float)
```

It gives me error
TypeError: could not convert string to float

Comment: Could you give us a reproducible example? For example, the output of `df.str.head()` would be helpful. If the string actually contains the percent symbol, you'll need to remove that. That's not a valid character is a string representing a float.

Comment: I want output 2.67% .I don't want to remove percent symbol in output keep as it is and  it should be in float so how we can achieve the desired output

Comment: You can't have the percent symbol in a numerical value. You need to strip it from the string, convert the remainder to float, do whatever calculations you need, and then when you need to print out the result, you add the `%` back *as a string*. The string `"40.39%"` cannot be converted to a number. The string `"40.39"` can.

Comment: ok so could you please let me know how to code then

Comment: If you want to work with percentages: `df.str.apply(lambda x: x.replace(',', '.').rstrip('%')).astype(float)`.
If you want to convert percentages into decimal (so 25% becomes 0.25), `df.str.apply(lambda x: x.replace(',', '.').rstrip('%')).astype(float) / 100'.